# How can I make my parameterized bit widths cleaner?

Tags: verilog

I'm often declaring bit widths like this:

```
parameter FOO_BITS=4;

reg    [(FOO_BITS-1):0] foo_1;
reg    [(FOO_BITS-1):0] foo_2;
```

That is, I declare a parameter for a width, and then I declare a data type whose width is that parameter **minus one**.

The **- 1** syntax is quite an eyesore to me. I could just say that `FOO_BITS=3`, but `4` more easily conveys the intent of the parameter to the reader: foo data types should have a width of 4 bits.

Is this just a Verilog fact of life? Is there any way to make this a little cleaner and less repetitive?

Comment: The standard is to start counting at 0, but you can start counting at 1 if you like.. i.e. `reg [1:Foo_BITS] foo_1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you're not likely to get rid of the `-1`s completely, unless you want to change the meaning of `FOO_BITS` or index from `0`, neither of which are recommended - they go against convention somewhat and will make it harder for anybody else to understand your code.  You could remove the brackets though which are superfluous and make the line harder to parse.

Another way to tidy things up is to use typedefs:

```
parameter                    FOO_BITS = 32;
typedef logic [FOO_BITS-1:0] word_t;

word_t foo_1;
word_t foo_2;
```

I find this also makes code more readable when using multi-dimensional arrays:

```
word_t               foo_3;
word_t [N_WORDS-1:0] foo_array;
```

Comment: As an aside: when using unpacked arrays the array declaration can be a little cleaner like this: `reg [FOO_BITS-1:0] foo_array [FOOWORDS]`

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to get rid of -1 either, but just like any other repetitive construct, you can hide it behind a macro:

```
`define RANGE(_WIDTH_)        _WIDTH_-1:0
```

Now you can define your array as:

```
reg    [`RANGE(FOO_BITS)]     foo_1;
```

Not sure if this is less of an eyesore, but it requires the reader to refer to the definition of RANGE.